# const keyword in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, constants

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {         
    @autoreleasepool {
      const int x = 1;
      const NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray array];
      const NSMutableString *str1 = @"1";
      NSString * const str2 = @"2";

      // x = 2; compile error
      [array1 addObject:@"2"]; // ok 
      // [str1 appendString:@"2"]; // runtime error
      // Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
      // str2 = @"3"; compile error
     }
 }
```

my Question is Why array1 addObject is legal and why str1 appendString is forbidden?

see this blow:

```
NSMutableString *f2(const NSMutableString * const x) {
  [x appendString: @" world!"];
  return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
      NSMutableString *x = [@"Hello" mutableCopy];
      NSLog(@"%@", f2(x));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and why this code is legal, how can I make an object immutable using 'const' keyword like in c++?

============================================
@see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151463/do-people-use-const-a-lot-when-programming-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'const' does nothing on Objective-C objects. You cannot do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that though you declared `str1` to be an instance of `NSMutableString`, it is in fact an instance of a different subclass of `NSString`--in particular, it is an instance of  `__NSCFConstantString` by default, though [this class can be changed by setting a compiler flag](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html#comment-9507fddba34a159ffac21fdbe7aecbab).  This is the sort of string that is returned from `@""`.

To fix this, just use

```
const NSMutableString *str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
```